# Windows server IP address

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2012, windows-10, virtualbox, opnsense

Currently, I'm using Oracle Virtual Box 7.0.12. My Windows 10 Server has a static IP address of 192.168.10.10/24. The roles I added were Active Directory, DHCP, DNS, and IIS services. However, it is then replaced with an IP address with the network address of 169.254.xxx.xxx for some unknown reason. It was functioning normally like a server should, but when I opened it one night, that's when the IP address got messed up. Promiscuous Mode is set to **Deny** for all virtual machines.

Here are the configurations I did when it was functional:

Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2

- IPv4 Address: 192.168.10.1/24
- Server Address: 192.168.10.10/24
- Host Addresses Range: 192.168.10.100/24 to 192.168.10.254/24

OPNSense (default gateway - preconfigured)

- IP Address: 192.168.10.1/24
- Adapter #1: Bridged Adapter
- Adapter #2: Host-Only Adapter, Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2

Windows 10 Server:

- IP Address: 192.168.10.10/24 (Static)
- Default Gateway: 192.168.10.1/24
- DNS Server: 192.168.10.10/24 and 8.8.8.8 (alternative)
- Adapter #1: Host-Only Adapter, Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2

I did some research on what the 169.245.xxx.xxx is. It was the default network address of a Windows computer if it encounters a problem in connecting to a DHCP server (e.g., DHCP Server not found). So far, I tried doing the following:

- Restarted my host PC and the virtual machines
- Reinstalled my Oracle VirtualBox, together with the missing independencies
- Manually configuring the IP address of my Windows server
- Checked if DHCP and DNS roles in Server Manager were enabled, which is enabled.
- Checked if Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2 is enabled
- Ran my VirtualBox as an administrator
- Checked my Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2 Configurations (before I reinstalled my VM, this was automatically changed into the 169.254.xxx.xxx address. So far after the installation, it didn't change)
- Pinging Windows server from OPNSense

What I need in goal is:

- For VirtualBox to recognize my Windows 10 Server's IP address as the "Server Address" as configured in the Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2 network (192.168.10.10/24).

Note: Before I got this problem, I didn't do any other configurations in the server, aside from the GPOs in setting the desktop background for users.

Your suggestions and answers will be very much appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: Have you checked the opnsense if there maybe also dhcp enabled there? For a proper working of opnsense you need to configure it a bit and just not the defaults only. I would use the bridged adapter by the way for both vms

Comment: Hi! Yes, my OPNSense is DHCP-enabled. The OVA file of OPNSense that was provided for me was already configured, which is why I didn't have to change anything. As for the network adapter, my windows server is required using only host-adapter #2. Only my OPNSense should be bridged.